# Usage of Custom attributes in vs2010

Tags: html

How to use custom data attributes of `jssor slider` in vs 2010 aspx page? Because when using the attributes `u=""`,`p=""`..., they are showing as invalid.Thus im not able to view the arrows and some symbols.

Is there any other way to use `jssor slider` in vs 2010 web application?

Answer (score 0):

Please use `data-u` instead of `u`.

Comment: I tried data-u also.Bt still it shows invalid attribute.

Comment: I see, but it doesn't matter. `data-u` is valid html5 custom attribute. To define a custom attribute, please add prefix `data-`.